# MSBuild batch task output

Tags: msbuild

I have several solutions (plugins) for a project. For each solution there is a defined range of metadata:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Plugins Include="Plugin1\Plugin1.sln">
        <Disabled>false</Disabled>
        <ProjectDirectory>plugin1\</ProjectDirectory>
        <ProjectName>Plugin1</ProjectName>
    </Plugins>
    <Plugins Include="Plugin2\Plugin2.sln">
        <Disabled>true</Disabled>
        <ProjectDirectory>plugin2\</ProjectDirectory>
        <ProjectName>Plugin2</ProjectName>
    </Plugins>
    <Plugins Include="Plugin3\Plugin3.sln">
        <Disabled>false</Disabled>
        <ProjectDirectory>plugin3\</ProjectDirectory>
        <ProjectName>Plugin3</ProjectName>
    </Plugins>
</ItemGroup>
```

I need to build not `Disabled` plugins by running its own build script and add the result directory to Plugins metadata for subsequent processing (for example: Copy each plugin build output to its own folder).

But I can't find a way to concatenate it.

Below is my target:

```
<Target Name="BuildPlugin" Inputs="%(Plugins.Identity)" Outputs="%(Plugins.Identity -> %(PluginOutput.Identity))" Returns="%(PluginOutput.Identity)">
    <MSBuild
        Condition="!%(Disabled)"
        Projects='%(ProjectDirectory)BuildProject.target'
        Targets="Clean;Build;" >

            <Output ItemName="PluginOutput" TaskParameter="TargetOutputs"/>
    </MSBuild>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Plugins Condition="%(ProjectName)=%(Plugins.ProjectName)">
            <PluginOutput>%(PluginOutput.Identity)</PluginOutput>
        </Plugins>
    </ItemGroup>

    <Message Text="%(Plugins.ProjectName) %(PluginOutput.Identity)"  Condition="%(Plugins.Disabled)" />
</Target>
```

`BuildProject.target` returns output directories (Ex:`Plugin1\Plugin1\bin\Release\`)

In this case buuilding fails with next errors:

> error MSB4096: item list "PluginOutput" does not define a value for
> metadata "ProjectName".  In order to use this metadata, either qualify
> it by specifying %(PluginOutput.ProjectName), or ensure that all items
> in this list define a value for this metadata.
>
> error MSB4113: Specified condition "%(Plugins.Disabled)" evaluates to
> "" instead of a boolean.

But if remove `ItemGroup`  and  condition for `Message` task

```
<Target Name="BuildPlugin" Inputs="%(Plugins.Identity)" Outputs="%(Plugins.Identity -> %(PluginOutput.Identity))" Returns="%(PluginOutput.Identity)">
    <MSBuild
        Condition="!%(Disabled)"
        Projects='%(ProjectDirectory)BuildProject.target'
        Targets="Clean;Build;" >

            <Output ItemName="PluginOutput" TaskParameter="TargetOutputs"/>
    </MSBuild>

    <Message Text="%(Plugins.ProjectName) %(PluginOutput.Identity)"  />
</Target>
```

seems msbuild correctly batches plugins. `BuildPlugin` target output produced by `Message` task is:

```
 BuildPlugin:
   Plugin1
     Plugin1\Plugin1\bin\Release\
 BuildPlugin:
   Plugin2
 BuildPlugin:
   Plugin3
     Plugin3\Plugin3\bin\Release
```

But in this case I don't have any ability to filter disabled plugins and add plugins output folder to metadata.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The following should work

```
<Target Name="BuildPlugin" Outputs="%(Plugins.Identity -> %(PluginOutput.Identity))" Returns="%(PluginOutput.Identity)">
    <MSBuild 
        Condition="!%(Plugins.Disabled)"
        Projects='%(Plugins.ProjectDirectory)BuildProject.target'
        Targets="Clean;Build;" >
            <Output ItemName="PluginOutput" TaskParameter="TargetOutputs"/>
    </MSBuild>


    <Message Text="%(Plugins.ProjectName) %(PluginOutput.Identity)" Condition="!%(Plugins.Disabled)"/>
</Target>
```

Comment: _%(Plugins.Disabled)_ evaluates into empty string in _Message_ task Condition but works fine for _MSBuild_ task. Seems that in _Message_ task msbuild tries to find metadata only in _PluginOutput_

Comment: Hmm, wouldn't think so. Do you get the value of %(Plugins.ProjectName) right if you remove the condition?

Comment: I  not completely understand why - but yes, without restrictions _Message_ task produces correct output, only problem is that includes all the items from _Plugins_ ItemGroup

Comment: Sorry for suggesting this but I have done it often as well. Have you checked the spelling of Disabled in the condition? If it is coming out to be empty, may be that is the problem

Comment: Already checked several times, but thank for suggestion. Misprint it's most dangerous issue (:

Comment: I just removed `Inputs="@(Plugins)"` from _Target_ and now Message task works fine

Comment: I see. Glad that it works. This is using global ItemGroups now. Doesn't explain when it works with MSBuild task and not with Message. Will explore it in the evening. I will edit my answer to remove Inputs

Comment: oops. In case of removing `Inputs="@(Plugins)"` `%(PluginOutput.Identity)` always returns latest output

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't test all steps, because of missing BuildProject.target, but this should work:

```
<Target  Name="BuildPlugin"
     Inputs="%(Plugins.Identity)"
     Outputs="%(Plugins.Identity)\dummy.txt"
     Returns="%(PluginOutput.Identity)">

 <PropertyGroup> <!-- transform Metadata to Properties -->
   <ProjectName>%(Plugins.ProjectName)</ProjectName>
   <PluginDisabled>%(Plugins.Disabled)</PluginDisabled>
 </PropertyGroup>

 <MSBuild
     Condition="'$(PluginDisabled)' != 'true'"
     Projects='%(Plugins.ProjectDirectory)BuildProject.target'
     Targets="Clean;Build;" >
   <Output ItemName="PluginOutput" TaskParameter="TargetOutputs"/>
 </MSBuild>

 <ItemGroup>
    <!-- batching 2 ItemGroups in one task is usually not working or creates side effects-->
   <Plugins Condition="'%(PluginOutput.ProjectName)' == '$(ProjectName)'">
     <PluginOutput>%(PluginOutput.Identity)</PluginOutput>
   </Plugins>
 </ItemGroup>

   <!-- batching 2 ItemGroups in one task is usually not working or creates side effects-->
 <Message Text="$(ProjectName) %(PluginOutput.Identity)"  Condition="$(PluginDisabled)" />
</Target>
```

Comment: I added explanation of BuildProject.target output into question: It returns plugin output directories

Comment: So in this case binding `Condition="'%(PluginOutput.ProjectName)' == '$(ProjectName)'"` would not work